# Huawei QuickApp configAuth fail 1002

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to develop an application using quickapp, right now I am trying to imlement account kit,
but when I execute this method below

```
account.authorize
```

it is throwing an error

```
Authorize configAuth fail 1002
```

but for example

```
account.getProvider();
```

is working and result is

```
huawei
```

I could not find what causes the error 1002. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether the RPK is of a formal build version and whether the signature is the same as that configured on HUAWEI Developer. For details please find below:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-access-account-kit

[image: Result Code]

Please resign your apk and hopefully your problem will be solved.